# php mysql_connect resource is allways the same

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I'm having a problem my php script witch you can see here:
http://codepad.org/F0qhElRC

Is not opening a new resource for each connection from a child.
Already I tryed using 127.0.0.1 or my local network IP but nothing worked,
also max_user_connections in mysql is set to 0 opening a connection from web gives me a different 
resource for the web. But in the command line it uses the same.

In mysql_connect I specified new_link to be true, I placed a __destruct in the bd class
to close the connection if the child get's destroyed. Closing the connection does not make 
php open a new one even after I restart the script. The resource could be free and so I should 
count on that but in the childs I also have tryed placing a sleep but that doesn't make it run 
a new resource.

Any sugestions on how to debug this?

Basically I whant a new conn for every new script or child call.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,

Comment: How do you determine if it's a new connection? By var_dumping the resource id? It's the same if you re-start your script.

Comment: I do a print of the resource $conn = mysql_connect(xxx);
print $conn."\n";
I know it may get reused but I don't understand how the childs of the fork end up using the same, since each childs opens a different connection.

I'm using php 5.3.6

Comment: `print $conn` just shows you the php resource ID, not a "connection ID" whatsoever. resource IDs are re-numbered from 0 when php starts.

Comment: But since I'm using the same script only diference is that it forks, it should return a diferent conn every time, right ? each connection will have a diferent resource ID, no ?

Comment: no. each fork has an own copy of the resource ID list, and it's always 0. they are not shared between forks/php processes.

Comment: So if the parent has a resource list = resource id #1 , the childs list will be resource list = null; if for each child I open a new connection then it should be the next resource available witch would be #0 ? Here I'm getting all the childs with the same resource.

Comment: No. your parent PHP process does not have any resource ID given out yet. So it's at 0 at the parent, and you're getting "1" in every child process.

Answer (score 2):

You've managed to omit all the relevant code, but many database extensions in PHP reuse currently open connections unless you specifically instruct them not to do so. If you are using [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect), have a look at the `$new_link` parameter:

```
mysql_connect — Open a connection to a MySQL Server
Report a bug
Description
resource mysql_connect ([ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )

Opens or reuses a connection to a MySQL server.
```

.

> new_link
>
> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same
>   arguments, no new link will be
>   established, but instead, the link
>   identifier of the already opened link
>   will be returned. The new_link
>   parameter modifies this behavior and
>   makes mysql_connect() always open a
>   new link, even if mysql_connect() was
>   called before with the same
>   parameters. In SQL safe mode, this
>   parameter is ignored.

Comment: $this->conn = mysql_connect( $this->_server, $this->_user, $this->_pass, true, MYSQL_CLIENT_COMPRESS ); Already have that , this is my mysql_connect line.

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1148-PHP-Easier-insert-update-methods-with-MySQL-.html I used this class has the base for my code witch has litle modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `sql.safe_mode` (check your configuration files)?  The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) for mysql_connect indicates that *new_link* is ignored in such cases.

Comment: it's off by default and I haven't enabled it.

grep -i sql.safe /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sql.safe_mode = Off